# C# - Extract Zip with file listing

Tags: c#, zip, extract

I would like to extract a pre-set zip file WITHOUT an external library to a given folder, and I would like to inform the user about the current percent of extraction (with a simple progressBar and a percent label) and the currently extracted file. Is this possible somehow?

It is important to do not use any other library.

(For updating all the labels and progressBar, I use a separate backgroundWorker)

Comment: Define "external library."  External as in outside of mscorlib?  Outside of `System`?  Outside of the default assemblies added to a certain Visual Studio project?  Outside of any Microsoft assemblies?

Comment: Usually "external library" means ANY library what is not included in standard .Net FrameWorks. In this case, 3.5 .